# Back Button functionality in App Locker

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to build an App Locker for Android, I have created a functionality to run a service in background and it opens a Lock screen and prompts  for the password, if some app is launched by user, I want to restrict the is user to not go to that launched app by pressing the back button on the lock screen.

Below is the code, i could see that the underlying activity is killed, but it is restarted again. please let me know if there is any way to make it work.

```
public void onBackPressed(){

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String pkg = (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo)am.getRunningTasks(2).get(1)).topActivity.getPackageName();
    am.killBackgroundProcesses(pkg);
    super.onBackPressed();
```

Comment: try to remove super.onBackPressed(); line and see

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        finish();
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        String pkg = (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo)am.getRunningTasks(2).get(1)).topActivity.getPackageName();
        am.killBackgroundProcesses(pkg);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```